# Emails marked as spam - SPF passes, DKIM passes, sender-id passes

Tags: email, gmail, dns, spf, dkim

I've been struggling to figure out why this is happening, but my emails are being marked as spam by Gmail and Hotmail (they work in Yahoo.)

SPF, DKIM, rDNS, and sender-id all pass. What's weirder is I've send the EXACT same email with its exact contents from my dev server and Gmail accepts it as not spam even though every one of those checks which passes in production fails in dev. Hotmail still marks it as spam though.

Any idea what could be going on? Here is an example header from Gmail (with IPs and domains changed for privacy):

```
Delivered-To: REMOVED@gmail.com
Received: by 10.194.16.130 with SMTP id g2csp192349wjd;
    Mon, 13 Aug 2012 14:04:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.236.193.105 with SMTP id j69mr12819871yhn.21.1344891849751;
    Mon, 13 Aug 2012 14:04:09 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <mailer@mydomain.com>
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (mydomain.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e22si563514yhh.132.2012.08.13.14.04.08
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
    Mon, 13 Aug 2012 14:04:09 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of mailer@mydomain.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of mailer@mydomain.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mailer@mydomain.com; dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com
Received: from mydomain.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by mail.mydomain.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu1) with ESMTP id q7DL48tq019625
for <REMOVED@gmail.com>; Mon, 13 Aug 2012 17:04:08 -0400
X-DKIM: OpenDKIM Filter v2.3.2 mail.mydomain.com q7DL48tq019625
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com;
s=server; t=1344891848;
bh=lpw+5POmINBjQYgQBdJvY2d+m84MY8hwTqZ6riNfH8I=;
h=Date:From:To:Message-ID:Subject:Mime-Version:Content-Type:
 Content-Transfer-Encoding;
b=KnYSvSzFewOGFyYWvP1DfCvyRfp6y31BfOPTOgRsZ7nGB4PXuau84euzuhs82V4lx
 ++DjN3iPxSj07euW+y7aRe9R2YiXKJFVNh7cbcJX8+tc3LMmnR7Cv27iP3Yvv6mQMd
 uz4Engql3bXLVVDKcLLj/Fj2eiwtWzW4chA2GNTQ=
Received: (from root@localhost)
by mydomain.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id q7DL48Dm019624
for REMOVED@gmail.com; Mon, 13 Aug 2012 17:04:08 -0400
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 17:04:08 -0400
From: "Website" <mailer@mydomain.com>
To: REMOVED@gmail.com
Message-ID: <50296bc866dfc_4b8593bd18556b8@mydomain.com.mail>
Subject: You've received a message from Bob.
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mydomain.com; q=dns/txt; s=server; t=1344891848; bh=LfadLl6eJEB+NgiTbBlcBhOt/9NKcG0wapkrAjlGqfg=; h=content-transfer-encoding:content-type:date:from:message-id:mime-version:subject:to; b=mTB8TBb+gG7ESxeVbfqHANKUMeNbdwK/hSIq58oin5ERNSMKOIvZKY9cQJRoY/Q96PQ7J+7b3ZkZuwcg+zMkQyhK7YACvFAz4SUWqpdqiZrBDw8Vqy3PjkGFcz2V5vyUOjI6vN/Y6iOj1zlocC+/p8lkpw3upwxr7cNoe5/Kwu8=
```

Answer (score 2):

The other guy doesn't know what he's talking about and just guessing.

'Received: (from root@localhost)' is your problem. That needs to reflect the from email...

Answer (score 0):

You problem is:

**domain:** mydomain.com
**ip:** xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

and **root@localhost** too

You need change informations in your mail client!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. In my case, I have configured my mail client correctly. I have one main domain (`mydomain.com`), my mail server also supports another domain (`mydomain2.com`) using virtual_domains. However, the emails for (`mydomain2.com`) always end up in Spam in Gmail. The mail-tester score for `mydomain2.com` is `9.7/10`. Here is the original header from Gmail (i have replaced IP and email address with example ips)

```
Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.80.177.154 with SMTP id m26csp9759783edd;
        Sat, 7 Jan 2017 16:28:58 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.84.128.67 with SMTP id 61mr108683153pla.153.1483835337902;
        Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:28:57 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <noreply@mydomain2.com>
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (xx-xxx-x-xxx.com. [xx.xxx.x.xxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s186si84168719pgb.6.2017.01.07.16.28.57
        for <myemail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:28:57 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@mydomain2.com designates xx.xxx.x.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xx.xxx.x.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain2.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@mydomain2.com designates xx.xxx.x.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@mydomain2.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain2.com
Received: from myhomerouter by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 284538419F for <myemail@gmail.com>; Sun,
  8 Jan 2017 00:28:57 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain2.com; s=mail; t=1483835337; bh=g3zLYH4xKxcPrHOD18z9YfpQcnk/GaJedfustWU5uGs=; h=From:Subject:Date:To:From; b=rwN/rSaqojz5pKVoYwb99Ec0TZzkHCo140KMlFVe47jl7Ui64w4DoNpCgZFeYEX87
     8NZuBQdfnrirZWbZ7ibydoi07Poz6PZjKoLdRToMcqrtcGVfA+UrJPGQ3EE/QrnYf4
     W0Hyb3PpUO+WVcwDL/rvvVm6ZnfjdIjobJpFj1fU=
From: First Name lastname <noreply@mydomain2.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 10.2 \(3259\))
Subject: Test
Message-Id: <8D89561C-0226-4C6B-A8D1-54A2F210F031@mydomain2.com>
Date: Sat, 7 Jan 2017 19:28:56 -0500
To: First Name <myemail@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.3259)

test
```